# Content Type Fails to send to Server through AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm having trouble posting JSON to a server as AJAX somehow abandon's the content type.[Using this library][1] as well as Jquery and Bootstrap I found the problem:

- Curl works for the post and retrieves success in Flask app when content is JSON.
- After multiple methods and ways, post works into the app but the ContentType fails to travel with the JSON
- Tried multiple ways to format the JSON and regardless content type is not recognized.
  Use

Here is the AJAX code:

```
var items;

$('#orderform').on('submit',function () {
    console.log(items);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/order",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"order": '555'}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
        var data = "Check";
        }
    });
```

Edit: This is the content type:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Edit 2: Using the absolute path for the webpage as the URL I find out that it receives a 405 not assigning the content header when posting back to the sever.

Edit 3: Here's the JSFiddle:

```js
var order;
var adjustment;

var group = $("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable({
  group: 'simple_with_animation',
  pullPlaceholder: false,
  // animation on drop
  onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {

    var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({
      height: 0
    });
    $item.before($clonedItem);
    $clonedItem.animate({
      'height': $item.height()
    });

    $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function() {
      $clonedItem.detach();
      _super($item, container);
    });
    var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();
    order = data[1];
    console.log(order);
  },

  // set $item relative to cursor position
  onDragStart: function($item, container, _super) {
    var offset = $item.offset(),
      pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer;

    adjustment = {
      left: pointer.left - offset.left,
      top: pointer.top - offset.top
    };

    _super($item, container);
  },
  onDrag: function($item, position) {
    $item.css({
      left: position.left - adjustment.left,
      top: position.top - adjustment.top
    });
  },
  serialize: function(parent, children, isContainer) {
    return isContainer ? children.join() : parent.text();
  },
  tolerance: 6,
  distance: 10
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(':button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(order);
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ec2-54-244-61-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/order",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "info": order
      }),
      async: false,
      success: function(result) {
        window.location.href = result.redirect;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      }
    });
  }); //END mybutton click

}); //END document.read
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.simple_with_animation li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  /** More li styles **/
}

ol.simple_with_animation li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  /** Define arrowhead **/
}

#GamblerOrderSource,
#GamblerOrderTarget {
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#GamblerOrderSource {
  border: 2px dashed #f8e0b1 !important;
  background-color: #fefcf5 !important;
}

#GamblerOrderTarget {
  border: 2px dashed #add38d !important;
  background-color: #f6fbf4 !important;
}

#GamblerOrderSource li {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
  color: #c09853;
}

#GamblerOrderTarget li {
  background-color: #ebf5e6;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  color: #468847;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<form id="orderform" method='POST'>
  <div id='GamblerOrderSource'>
    <ol class='simple_with_animation'>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id='GamblerOrderTarget'>
    <ol class='simple_with_animation'>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

le

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataType: 'json'` to send `json` data. You are not sending json data on server. you need to change `dataType` to send `json` data

Try use this ajax code, no need to stringify json object if its already correct object. i have tested it at my side hopefully it will help you.

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: "YOUR PATH TO FILE OR METHOD",
 data:{
  order:'555'
 },
 dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    if(data['success']=='true'){
     echo 'success';
    }else{
    if(data['success']=='false'){
     echo 'not success';
    }
   }
  }, 
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   console.log(status);
   console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Making the modification still didn't send the JSON data type to the server and trigger the right response.  Thanks for helping out by the way.

Comment: No I did not, I'm still going through it.  It's been puzzling me.  So I know that if I use the absolute URL and post to said url "/order" it will post a 405.

Comment: `url: "/order"` what is `/order` is order a function ?

Comment: /order is a GET/POST method.  When retrieved as a GET, it should return a page that allows user input.  Then, when triggering a POST, it should submit the data then direct to a new page.

Comment: Hello, first off thank you, and second of all I'm almost there, I get this error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Xb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Also when changing it to proper JSON code with double quotes and JSON Stringify it gets a 405 Bad Request.

Comment: Found out that your method worked, I just didn't clarify it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your dataType:"text/html; charset=utf-8" to`dataType:json`